# Why I'm obtaining that error "docker: Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is supported on user defined networks only."?

Tags: docker

I wanna run my container with the ip 0.0.0.0 exposed, but I received the next error, and I would like to know the reason, and a possible solution.

```
docker run --name test1 -p 8080:8080 --ip=0.0.0.0 -it ubuntu:latest bash
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is
>   supported on user defined networks only.

I want to see in my local machine the process running in the port 8080

Comment: As for a possible solution, tell us a little bit more what you want to achieve by putting `0.0.0.0` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just delete the `--ip` option; the `-p` option will do what you want.

0.0.0.0 is a special IP address that means “everywhere”.  You can’t set a container’s IP address to be “everywhere”; that specific `--ip` option is invalid.

Usually you don’t need or want to explicitly set a container’s IP address.  Your `-p` option will route traffic from the host’s port 8080 to the container’s port 8080, which is the correct way to publish container services out of Docker space.  (There actually is an implicit `-p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080` hidden there; on a multi-interface host you can specify an explicit bind address.)